# How the to remove that menu at top right? inside the red circle in shown pictures

Tags: slideshows

[image: three horizontal lines menu]

[image: three horizontal lines menu]

Hello, I was studying about slides in Mathematica but for some reason this menu got stuck on ALL notebooks and menus and even the start page is affected as you can see on the pictures. it is a little annoying and I couldn't find a way to remove it. Restarting didn't work, the menu it is still there. It appears on all notebooks, whether being slides or non-slides, new ones and old ones. can someone give me a hand with it?

I know it has something to do with slide show palette but nothing seems to be able to remove it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange. Have you tried [resetting Mathematica](https://support.wolfram.com/12464)? Read the manuals carefully, though (back up, reactivation ...).

Comment: I worked. Thanks @Domen